# Conditional distribution of $Z = (X-Y) / 3$, given $Y = y$

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics

I'm trying to solve this problem, but without much success. Here we have that $X \sim \operatorname{Geo}(\theta)$, with $p(x) = \theta (1 - \theta)^x$, and 
$Y = X \mod 3$, thereby having $p(y) = \theta\frac{ (1 - \theta)^y}{
1 - (1 - \theta)^3}$, with $y = 0, 1, 2.$

Now I have to find the conditional distribution of $ Z = (X-Y)/3$, given $Y = y.$ I haven't found anything like this here (sorry if I duplicated a question, I tried not to). Can anyone help?

Comment: Note that $Y \in \{0,1,2\}$ .  Given $Y$, you can easily calculate all possible values of $X$, and therefore the probability distribution of $X$ (just the normalized sum of the probabilities for the possible values of $X$.)  After that, it should be obvious how to get to the conditional distribution of $Z|Y$.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, but I still don't think it's that obvious ):

Comment: Please check that the corrections I made to your definitions and formulas conform with your intention.

Comment: @whuber how do you got this distribution for Y?

Comment: Let $y\in\{0,1,2\}$. Then $$\eqalign{\Pr(Y=y)&=\Pr(X\in\{y,y+3,\ldots,y+3n,\ldots\})\\&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\theta(1-\theta)^{y+3n}\\&=\theta(1-\theta)^y\sum_{n=0}^\infty ((1-\theta)^3)^n\\&= \theta\frac{(1-\theta)^y}{1-(1-\theta)^3}.}$$(I accidentally dropped the factor of $\theta$ in my original edit.)

Comment: thanks! there is just a missing $\theta$ in the question.

Comment: nice! now, could you help me with the rest of the question, please?

Comment: Try working it out conditional upon $Y=0$.  Once you've figured that out, the rest should be easier.  What values can $X$ take when $Y=0$?  And what is the probability distribution associated with those values?

Comment: This sounds like a `self-study` tag is needed for this question. Please read the associated wiki and detail why you cannot solve the question.

Comment: I got P(Z = (X + Y)/3) = P(X = 3z + y) = $\theta (1 - \theta)^{3z + y}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps a solution based on understanding what geometric distributions *mean* would be of more interest than a purely algebraic one.

#### Preliminaries: notation; Geometric distributions

Recall that a Geometric distribution with parameter $\theta$ describes the chances of observing a sequence of $x\in\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$ failures before the first success in a series of independent Bernoulli$(\theta)$ trials, whose values I will write $U_1,U_2, \ldots, U_n,\ldots,$ encoding (as usual) $U_i=1$ to represent success. Writing $p_\theta(x)$ for those quantities, independence implies

$$p_\theta(x+1) = p_\theta(x)\Pr(U_{n+1}=1) = p_\theta(x)\theta.$$

Conversely, this relation completely determines the distribution from the facts that (1) all probabilities must sum to unity and (2) the nonzero probabilities are those for $x\in\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$.

#### Solution

Let's interpret the $Y$ and $Z$ of the problem.  It is an obvious number-theoretic fact that any possible value $x$ of $X$ can be written in the form $$x=3z+y$$ where $y\in\{0,1,2\}$ and $z\in\{0,1,2,\ldots\}.$   When we condition on $Y=y$, we're saying there initially are $y$ failures and then there are $z$ *groups* of three failures each before success is observed.  The independence of the Bernoulli trials in each group of three implies any sequence of three failures has a chance

$$\rho = (1-\theta)^3.$$

Consequently, the independence of each (nonoverlapping) group of three failures implies

$$\Pr(Z=z+1) = \Pr(Z=z) (1-\theta)^3= \Pr(Z=z) \rho$$

for any $z=0,1,2,\ldots.$  Thus, conditional on $Y=y$, **$Z$ has a Geometric distribution with parameter $\rho$.**

Among the salient implications of this observation--ones that immediately solve the problem--are

1. The distribution of $Z$ is independent of $Y$.
2. The distribution of $Z$ is Geometric with parameter $\rho=(1-\theta)^3.$
3. You can write the probabilities down immediately using the usual formulas for the geometric distribution, using the parameter $\rho$.

---

For those who prefer pure algebra, an amusing (and perhaps surprising) solution method is provided by the technique of *decimation* described at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/35138/919.  This directly gives the distributions of $(Y,Z)$, from which the conditional distribution of $Z$ is found by dividing by the chance that $Y=y$.