# Which is higher? - variance of a real-valued normal random variable or variance of integer rounding of that real-valued normal random variable?

Tags: variance, covariance

Let *A_r* be a real-valued normal random variable whose mean is an integer A.

Let *A_i* be the rounding of *A_r* such that *A_r* = *A_i* + e, where *e* is an uniformly distributed random variable taking the value from -0.5 to 0.5.

Now taking variance,

*Var(A_r)=Var(A_i)+var(e)+cov(A_i,e)=Var(A_i)+1/12+cov(A_i,e);*

What would be the *cov(A_i,e)*? Will it be less than -1/12 so that *Var(A_r)* is always less than *Var(A_i)*?

Comment: It can go either way.  For a family of examples, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/35138/919.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for the info.

Comment: You're welcome.  Please note that the rounding error is not usually uniformly distributed, although in the case of a Normal random variable $A$ it may be remarkably close to uniform: see the discussion of method 8 at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/117711/919.  This raises questions concerning what you are trying to ask: is your question actually about rounding or is it about adding uniformly-distributed noise to a variable?

Comment: @whuber Thanks. It is about rounding in my question. I assumed rounding a normal random variable would generate error which is uniformly distributed.

Comment: It's a fair assumption but not quite correct. At best we can say the distribution of errors will be *symmetric* if and only if the mean of the Normal variable is an integral multiple of $1/2.$ Since all uniform distributions on intervals are symmetric, this rules out that possibility in general.  As an extreme example consider a Normal distribution with a mean of $1/4$ and such a tiny standard deviation that almost all its probability lies between $0$ and $1/2.$ Most of the rounding errors will be in the interval $[-1/2,0],$ showing they cannot be uniformly distributed on $[-1/2,1/2].$