# Why does the sum of Poisson distributed random variables have a Poisson distribution but the average of the variables do not?

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

From a biology background and not strong in statistics.

From what I have read the sum of Poisson distributed random independent variables have a Poisson distribution but the average of these variables do not have a Poisson distribution. Why is that, can someone show me the maths?

I thought the average would still have a Poisson distribution.

Some background: this concerns technical replicates in RNA-seq. Marioni et al found that technical replicates follow a Poisson distribution. Tools that accommodate  technical replicates sum the values but do not average the values. I can accept this at face value but I would like to understand the maths/stats behind this.

Comment: A simple explanation would be to say that while a Poisson distribution only takes integer values, the average can take rational values

Comment: Thank you, that helps me understand a bit more

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/35042 is related: it shows that even when you round the average of independent Poisson variables you still don't get a Poisson distribution.

Comment: The average will approximately follow a Gaussian distribution as a consequence of the central limit theorem.

Comment: @oliversm - that Gaussian approximation is also true in the same sense (convergence in distribution of a standardised version) of a Poisson distribution as its parameter increases, and so of the sum of independent Poisson distributed random variables.

Comment: Not only is the support wrong as noted above but scaling (dividing by number of terms in the average) destroys the variance=mean property of the Poisson)

Answer (score 18):

Comment in answer format to show simulation:

@periwinkle's Comment that the average takes non-interger values should be enough.
However, the mean and variance of a Poisson random variable are numerically equal,
and this is not true for the *mean* of independent Poisson random variables. Easy
to verify by standard formulas for means of variances of linear combinations.
Also illustrated by a simple simulation in R as below:

```
set.seed(827)
x1 = rpois(10^4, 5); x2 = rpois(10^4, 10); x3 = rpois(10^4, 20)
t = x1+x2+x3;  mean(t);  var(t)
[1] 35.0542    # mean & var both aprx 35 w/in margin of sim err
[1] 35.14318
a = t/3;  mean(a);  var(a)
[1] 11.68473   # obviously unequal for average of three
[1] 3.904797
```

$E((X_1+X_2+X_3)/ 3) = 1/3(4 + 10 + 20) = 35/3,$
$Var((X_1+X_2+X_3)/3) = 1/9(5 + 10 + 20) = 35/9\ne 35/3.$

Comment: This is useful, because it points out that the problem here isn't merely a discrete/non-discrete problem, but that average changes the shape of the curve.

Comment: @BruceET: Sorry, I don't follow. 35/3=11.6666... which is quite close to the mean(a) and 35/9=3.8888... which is quite close to var(a).
[This is not a response to the original question: I was not able to comment [Bruce's](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/484932/199161) response because I don't have enough privileges]

Comment: @IuriGavronski: BruceET's point is that the average has its expected value $n$ times its variance, while a Poisson distribution has the mean and varaince the same.  I made a similar point in [an answer to the linked question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/35052/2958)

Answer (score 16):

The [Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) is a probability distribution defined on the set $\mathbb N$ of natural numbers $0,1,2,\dots$.
We also say that $\mathbb N$ is the *support* of the Poisson distribution. This distribution is often used to model experiments whose outcomes represent counts.

If $X$ is a random variable following a Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda$ then for a natural number $k \in \mathbb N$,
$$
\mathbb P(X=k) = e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^k}{k!}.
$$

It can be shown that the sum $X+Y$ of two *independent* Poisson-distributed variables $X,Y$ still follows a Poisson distribution.

Now, assume that you have $N$ independent random variables  $X_1, \dots, X_N$ each of them following a Poisson distribution.
Their sum $X_1+ \dots + X_N$ will be a natural number and by an induction reasonment we can show that $X_1+ \dots + X_N$ also follows a Poisson-distribution.

However their average, $\frac{X_1 + \dots + X_N}{N}$, does not need to be a natural number.
For example if $N=3$ and $X_1 = 1, X_2 = 0, X_3 = 7$ then $\frac{X_1 +X_2 + X_3}{3} = \frac{8}{3} \approx 2.67.$
Thus the average of Poisson random variables can take non-integer values (but it also can take integer values) which is against the definition of a Poisson distribution.
More precisely, the support of the average is not $\mathbb N$ but rather belongs to $\mathbb Q$ the set of [rational numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_number) (which contains $\mathbb N$).
This means that the average can't (by definition) follow a Poisson distribution.

---

In the same spirit, the statement above "It can be shown that the sum $X+Y$ of two *independent* Poisson-distributed variables $X,Y$ still follows a Poisson distribution" is not true if $X$ and $Y$ are not independent anymore.
Take for example $Y=X$ (thus $X$ and $Y$ are not independent) then the sum $X+Y=2X$ only takes even values and thus $\mathbb P(2X=1) = \mathbb P(2X=3) = \dots = 0$ which is not in agreement with the definition of a Poisson distribution since the quantity $e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^k}{k!}$ is strictly greater than $0$ *for all* natural numbers $k$.

I hope this is clear enough to help.

Comment: Can you clarify what ‘support’ means? Support of the average and N is the support of the Poisson distribution? Your post has really helped me to understand, I’m satisfied that I know the why.

Comment: The support of a distribution is the set of values it can take. That is, a poisson distribution can only take "whole-number" values, but the mean might not be a whole number (it might be a fraction). That is how we know the mean can't follow a poisson distribution, because fractions are impossible under that distribution.